# Cannot implicitly convert type float to bool weird error

Tags: c#

I'm trying to compare a float variable to the value of a dictionary key. But I get the error saying it can't be converted from float to bool. The value of the dictionary is a unsigned integer that I cast as a float.

```
    void RunAnimation()
    {
        float aloop = (float)AnimationLoop[CurrentAnimation];

        if(frame%aloop)
        {

        }
    }
```

Doing this causes an error on the if statement saying "Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'bool'". But both values are clearly float, I don't understand how its coming out something else.

Comment: What do you expect `if(frame%aloop)` to do? The problem is with that line.

Comment: wow I just figured it out the moment I reloaded the page. I forgot to add ==value. Sorry for the dumb question.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in C/C++, but not in C#. You need to write this:

```
if ((frame % aloop) != 0)
```

In C/C++ a `bool` is actually just an numeric value that's either 0 (false) or some other value (true). In your case, `frame % aloop` would be a "valid bool" in C/C++.

C# on the other hand really expects a `bool` expression, however `frame % aloop` evaluates to a numeric type. Thus the error.

Comment: Yeah I'm abit used to it working that way, and figuring out I forgot something when the statement always comes up true.